# Subtract two columns of lists in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with two columns of 1D lists of the same size, and I would like to form a third column with the difference of these vectors. Conceptually:

```
df['dV'] = df['v1'] - df['v2']
```

So that if `df['v1']` looks like:

```
0  [0.2, 0.1, 0.0]
1  [0.5, -0.4, 0.0]
...
```

and `df['v2']` looks like:

```
0  [0.1, 0.6, 0.0]
1  [0.5, 0.4, 0.0]
...
```

then the desired result `df['dV']` would be:

```
0  [0.1, -0.5, 0.0]
1  [0.0, -0.8, 0.0]
...
```

I have tried the following:

```
df['dV'] = df['v1'] - df['v2']
```

which results in an "operands could not be broadcast.." error. Next, I tried:

```
vecsub = lambda x, y: np.subtract(x, y)
df['dV'] = list(map(vecsub, df['v1'], df['v2']))
```

This produces a result, but the types are different:

```
type(df['dV'])
```

is `numpy.ndarray`

while

```
type(df['v1'])
```

is `list`.

How might I simply get the results in dV as lists? Applying numpy's `tolist` around my lambda outputs `<built-in method tolist of numpy.ndarray object>` for every value in the dataframe.

Comment: hey buddy did you downvote me? my answer works perfecly fine

Comment: I did not downvote - haven't had a chance to try yet

Comment: Standard warning: pandas doesn't have strong support for non-scalar entries.  You get slow performance (because the necessary dtype is object) and are apt to encounter obscure and confusing behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change `ndarray` to `list` just do `list(df['dV'])`
Broadcasting errors happen usually when arrays have different size. Are you sure their shapes are equal? You can use `.shape` to get that information. You can read more about broadcasting [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

> Applying numpy's tolist around my lambda outputs `<built-in method tolist of numpy.ndarray object>` for every value in the dataframe.

Thats because you did: `someArray.tolist`, instead of `someArray.tolist()`, so you are actually printing function, not calling it and then printing it's result.

Comment: `tolist()` solves my issue with the type, thank you. Strange that `np.shape(df['v1']) == np.df(train['v2'])` is `True` despite the broadcast error. I will do more reading to understand.